# Create user home directory on a network share

Tags: networking, 20.04, home-directory, sharing, redirect

I have Ubuntu 20.04 machine that I'm preparing for VDI environment.
All the VDI VMs will be joined to our domain.
By default, each user's Home Directory is created locally.
On my NetApp storage I have a shared folder.
My question is - Is it possible to configure that for each user that logs in, his Home Directory will be created on this shared folder in the NetApp? Can I set /home to be this shared folder for each AD user?
My goal is to preserve the user's Home Directory regardless the machine he logs in to, otherwise he will lose his Home Directory on each login because the users are logs in to a different VM randomly each time.
And my additional sub question is - Can I redirect to the same folder all the user's apps and packages he is installing?

I'm not familiar so much with Linux so I'll appreciate for you help.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

it's possible by using autofs. have the directories pre-created and it works for simple things.

The issue is that homes on nfs is not wronging very well in more modern lines like Ubuntu. I have a setup like the one you are describing and I'm training to migrate away form it.